# How to select and fire an event on expanded item in expanderview

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have designed an expanderview in windows phone.

And now I want to select the expanded item and navigate it to other page.How to navigate it.

**My Xaml code for expanderview**

```xml
  <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->

   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="TeluguOne" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Videosongs" Margin="9,-7,0,0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
       <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="Latest movies" x:Name="expander" 
                             Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="35" 
                             Style="{StaticResource ExpanderViewStyle1}"   >

                <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Julayi" Foreground="Gray" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="ShiridiSai" Foreground="Gray" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Srimanarayana" Foreground="Gray" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Sudigadu" Foreground="Gray" />
            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
        </toolkit:ExpanderView>

        <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="New movies" FontSize="35" x:Name="expander1" 
                              Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                              Style="{StaticResource ExpanderViewStyle3}"  >
            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Dookudu" Foreground="Gray"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Mr.Perfect" Foreground="Gray" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Raccha"  Foreground="Gray"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Teenmar" Foreground="Gray" />
            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>


        <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="Old movies" FontSize="35" x:Name="expander2" 
                              Style="{StaticResource ExpanderViewStyle2}"  >
            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Mayabazar" Foreground="Gray"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Alluddin Adbhutha Deepam" 
                           Foreground="Gray" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>

        </toolkit:ExpanderView>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>.
```

MY screenshot of the expaderview is

[image]

In the above screenshot i need to select julayi and one after the other movies and navigate to other page.

Please anybody help me how can I select the expanded items and perform events on it.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you wanted to navigate when you tap on the Julayi which is ideally a `TextBlock`. Did you try using the `Tap` or the `Click` event within the textblock?

Comment: ha yes thank you it worked with Tap event.